# What does ParseError(NotEnough) from rust-chrono mean?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I'm using [`rust-chrono`](https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-chrono) and I'm trying to parse a date like this:

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::*;

fn main() {

    let date_str = "2013-02-14 15:41:07";
    let date = DateTime::parse_from_str(&date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    match date {
        Ok(v) => println!("{:?}", v),
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e)
    }

}
```

And this is the output:

```
ParseError(NotEnough)
```

What does this mean? Not enough of what? Should I be using some other library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use

```
UTC.datetime_from_str(&date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
```

Like:

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::*;

fn main() {

    let date_str = "2013-02-14 15:41:07";
    let date = UTC.datetime_from_str(&date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    match date {
        Ok(v) => println!("{:?}", v),
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e)
    }

}
```

Comment: Updated: `NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").map(|ndt| DateTime::<Utc>::from_utc(ndt, Utc))`

Comment: @MingweiSamuel I'm guessing the update is due to "UTC" no longer being a part of Chrono? But is your suggestion seriously the most succinct way of parsing a datetime with a known timezone (that isn't included in the string)? I'm just a bit astounded as this seems like a fairly common need.

Comment: It should be Utc: https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html

Answer (score 12):

Types that implement `Error` have more user-friendly error messages via `Error::description` or `Display`:

```
Err(e) => println!("{}", e)
```

This prints:

> input is not enough for unique date and time

Presumably this is because you haven't provided a timezone, thus the time is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

The ParseError(NotEnough) shows up when there is not enough information to fill out the whole object. For example the date, time or timezone is missing.

In the example above the timezone is missing. So we can store it in a [NaiveDateTime](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.11/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDateTime.html). This object does not store a timezone:

```
let naive_datetime = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").unwrap();
```

For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61179071/2037998

Answer (score -1):

With latest version of chrono (0.4.35) it's like:
`NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(&date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")?.and_utc();`

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: But you still haven’t explained what you’re doing or why this is preferred over other answers. Can you?