# How to parse timestamp by chrono?

Tags: rust, time

I am working with chrono and already spent 3 days for this. Still can't understand. What is a format of time like? How to parse this format?

Example of time is

```
2023-10-02T18:03:02.773+0000
```

The problem is in 'T' It's not a symbol as i can see. All my tries are failed

my code to parse is

```
let time = "2023-10-02T09:31:02.773+0000";
let date = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(time, "%Y-%m-%DT%x%z").unwrap();
```

Also i used formats like

```
%+
rfc3389
rfc2822
%FT%x
%FT%H:%M%S
%FT%H:%M%S%f
%FT%H:%M%S%f%z
%FT%H:%M%S%z
%FT%H:%M%S%.f
```

No one of this formats is not working. All the time `thread 'main' panicked at 'called 'Result::unwrap()' on an 'Err' value: ParseError(Impossible)`
How to format this example of time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust Chrono parse date String, ParseError(NotEnough) and ParseError(TooShort)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179070/rust-chrono-parse-date-string-parseerrornotenough-and-parseerrortooshort)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct format is `"%Y-%m-%dT%X%.f%z"`.

```rust
let time = "2023-10-02T18:03:02.773+0000";
let date = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%X%.f%z").unwrap();
```

Comment: @JaredSmith `DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339` doesn't work for OP's input since the offset must be `+00:00` (or `Z`) instead of `+0000`.